# Wie nennt man jemanden, der das Lernen liebt?

Tags: translation, noun

Es gibt die englische und scheinbar deutlich [antiquierte](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/philomath) Bezeichnung [Philomath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philomath). Der naheliegendste deutsche Begriff, den ich fand, ist [Philomathie](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Philomathie). Laut Duden ist dieser ebenfalls veraltet. Gibt es gegenwärtig eine sachliche Bezeichnung (Substantiv) für solche Menschen?

Comment: Ich werfe mal die Adjektive _wissbegierig_, _wissensdurstig_ und _bildungshungrig_ in den Raum.

Comment: Je nach Kontext könnte man  _Bücherwurm_ verwenden. Wobei sich das auf alle Bücher beziehen kann, nicht nur Lehrbücher.

Comment: *philoman* - Das sind die "krankhaft Wissbegierigen"

Comment: Ich suche gezielt nach einem Substantiv, das hätte ich vielleicht explizit erwähnen sollen.

Answer (score 3):

Ein Substantiv welches mir dazu in den Sinn kommt:

> *"[Autodidakt](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Autodidakt)"*

Es weist jedoch nicht direkt auf eine Person hin, die das Lernen liebt, sondern ein Selbststudium betreibt. Allerdings weist es auf eine gewisse Affinität im Bezug auf das Lernen hin.

Stattdessen kann man auf Formulierungen mit passenden Adjektiven zurückgreifen (geordnet nach ihrer [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bildungsbeflissen%2Cwissbegierig%2Cbildungshungrig%2Cwissensdurstig&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbildungsbeflissen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwissbegierig%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbildungshungrig%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwissensdurstig%3B%2Cc0) Popularität):

> Option 1: "*[wissbegierige](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wissbegierig) Person*"
>
> Option 2: "*[wissendurstige](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wissensdurstig) Person*"
>
> Option 3: "*[bildungsbeflissene](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bildungsbeflissen) Person*"
>
> Option 4: "*[bildungshungrige](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bildungshungrig) Person*"
>
> Option 5: "*philomatische Person*" (sehr alte Bezeichnung z.B. [hier](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nYUXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA400&lpg=PA400&dq=philomathisch&source=bl&ots=q-7ODYQOHT&sig=rFbtaohAX3KWg_MiH1iFaWtxJG0&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=philomathisch&f=false) genannt)

Dazugehörige Google ngrams Grafik:

[image: Google ngrams Popularität]

Comment: Nicht über "wissbegierig" wundern, das wurde vor 1996 anders geschrieben: [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bildungsbeflissen%2Cwissbegierig%2Bwi%C3%9Fbegierig%2Cbildungshungrig%2Cwissensdurstig&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbildungsbeflissen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28wissbegierig%20%2B%20wi%C3%9Fbegierig%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbildungshungrig%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwissensdurstig%3B%2Cc0)